# How can I test the page-controller I just created in salesforce?

Tags: view, controller, salesforce, visualforce

I have a trial developer license with salesforce and following the tutorials I don't see how can I access the page seeing it from a browser.

The closest help is this : "Now access your page with a valid Account identifier passed in as a parameter. Your URL will look something like:
https://na6.visual.force.com/apex/MyAccountWithExtension?id=0018000000MDfn1"

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write on the URL :

https://YOURINSTANCE.visual.force.com/apex/YOURPAGE?id=RECORDID

https://na6.visual.force.com/apex/MyAccountWithExtension?id=0018000000MDfn1

Have a nice day!
;)

Comment: Thank you very much!! It pointed me in the right direction, and was able to access it. I didn't know that "YOURINSTANCE" was the hostname of my salesforce instance (i.e, na3.salesforce.com)